# Marble testing observable that changes after a method call?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine

In Angular 8, I have a service with a readonly `Observable` property, spawned from a `BehaviorSubject<string>` that contains a string describing the service's state. Also in the service are methods that change the state of the service.

```
export class StateService {
  private _state = new BehaviorSubject<string>('before');

  readonly state$ = this._state.asObservable();

  constructor () { }

  begin() { this._state.next('during'); }

  finish() { this._state.next('after'); }

  reset() { this._state.next('before'); }
}
```

What I want to do is write marble tests in my Jasmine suite to elegantly test the value of this observable as it would change.

```
let scheduler: TestScheduler;

beforeEach(() => {
  scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
});

it('should flow states correctly', () => {
  scheduler.run(({expectObservable, flush}) => {
    const svc = setupSvc(); //Call to a function in the suite that sets up the StateService

    svc.begin();
    svc.finish();
    svc.reset();

    flush();

    expectObservable(svc.state$).toBe('a-b-c-d', {
      a: 'before',
      b: 'during',
      c: 'after',
      d: 'before'
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried varying combinations of calling `begin`, `finish`, `reset`, and the scheduler's `flush` helper, but the expectation always reports just the one initial value (the `a` marble) and no others.

What am I missing to be able to pull this off? Or are marbles the wrong way to go about testing this?

Comment: are you sure it is `a` and not `d`? not sure about rxjs-marbles(used only jasmine's), but seems '10ms(-)' is not "working here" and it could emit only last value - `d`

Comment: assumption: after calling all method `state$` would be only the last one, such as `BehaviourSubject` `asObservable` is a single value

Comment: @andriishupta That is possible, hard to tell in this case since `a` and `d` have the same value and the reporter is only showing one value emitted from the observable regardless of where I put `flush()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribing to a cold observable produced via the test helper seems to work:

```
it('should flow states correctly', () => {
  scheduler.run(({ expectObservable, cold }) => {
    const svc = new StateService();

    cold('--a-b-c', {
      a: 'begin',
      b: 'finish',
      c: 'reset'        
    }).subscribe(methodName => {
      svc[methodName]();
    })

    expectObservable(svc.state$).toBe('a-b-c-d', {
      a: 'before',
      b: 'during',
      c: 'after',
      d: 'before'
    });
  });
});
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing-iraomx?file=src%2Fstate-service.spec.ts)